# How can I open a password protected PPT & PDF

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to check if a PPT file is passsword protected. I am using Office interops. I found that Presentations.Open function doesn't accept a password as parameter.

Is there any other way to check a file is password protected.

I need to do the same for pdf files also.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554892/unable-to-gracefully-abort-on-unknown-password-via-microsoft-office-interop-powe

Answer (score 0):

For PPT files I don't think this is possible. Or at least using the object model, I suppose that you might be able to use Windows API functions to find the password dialog and send in the password to it but that wouldn't be very robust.